# Django: capturing values in url to generic class view

Tags: django, django-views

So I have the url:

```
url(r'^mousesmall/(?P<name>.*)/$', IDView.as_view()),
```

and my view is:

```
class IDView(DetailView):
    model = RNA
    template_name = "home/details.html"
```

Since I'm using the generic view detailview, how would I pass the name value that's captured in the URL to my detail view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base `View` class that `DetailView` inherits from sets the args and kwargs to `self.args` and `self.kwargs` respectively early in the processing. Since it's a named pattern, it should be in `self.kwargs['name']`.

Comment: I get name 'self' is not defined.

Comment: Where are you trying to access the parameter? `self` should definitely be defined inside the view methods - unless you've declared them differently, which would generally be a bad idea.

Comment: I'm trying to access it within the view, I've added "target_id = self.kwargs['name']" right below my template_name code above.

Comment: That's not how it works - that would be setting a class-level definition. Instead, use it in your `get` method - or if you're just planning to display it in your template, the `get_context_data` method.